# Max. Session Length in SP2010

Tags: session

i want to specify the maximum number of minutes an active user session may remain open before ending. In other words, how can i specify Max. Session Length in SP2010

Comment: Are you using FBA?  Standard Windows (Kerb/NTLM) will not support this.

Comment: I actually don't know the authentication that the client is using. But, can you specify how I can implement it using FBA or Claims based authentication ?